# How to download YUI compressor for minification only

Tags: javascript, yui, minify

I'm trying to download the YUI compressor to use on a Windows 7 platform. How do you do that?

PS. I don't need to build it or anything like that, all I need is an exe file to run to compress my js files. Is there an easy way to download it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745/does-a-yui-compressor-gui-app-exist

Comment: I don't need gui. All I need is to download the damn thing...

Comment: a GUI and exe file are the same thing sometimes...

Comment: OK, I agree with you. So how can I download one?

Comment: You can either download from YUI site and build it yourself or find a pre-built version hosted somewhere else (and be careful from where you download).

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded the jar version from [here](http://yuilibrary.com/download/yuicompressor/) and just built it from .

```
unzip Downloads/yuicompressor-2.4.7.zip
cd yuicompressor-2.4.7
ant
```

Instead of command line unzip, you can download 7-zip or something to extract it.

And it works:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```